# how to get last typed or pasted substring in a text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a scenario i which i want to get the substing that was typed or pasted at the last position in the TextBox

eg: when i type " hello how are you  "

-- it alerts for each words ie.

alert 1: hello

alert 2: how

alert 3: are

alert 4: you

but if i paste "HelloHowareYou" it will alert HelloHowareYou

i get the last cursor position by caret function but i am not able to proceed further for getting the last substing from the string . for performance optimisation i dont want to use split function

Answer (score 3):

as a general idea, you need to save the content of textbox in a variable. when the value of textbox changes, compare that with the previous value and the difference would be your new string.
I have quickly mocked up a working example (not completely tested) here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pf6hP/

is that what you are looking for?

**EDIT**: based on your comment, I modified the script to watch out for space so it gets the last word. check the working demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pf6hP/1/

if you need any improvements or explanation, please ask.

Comment: actually, i dont think i understand your question, but from what i gather, you want the recently entered text / letter ?

Comment: na ... its recently entered word (sub-string)

Comment: @Umbrella, so if you already have ``who came here`` in the textbox, and now enter ``before`` (so the text box now has ``who came here before``) you want ``before`` - is that right? I thought its the last key. so if you want last word, you just need to watch out for space. thats easy too.

Comment: hi, updated the answer. Check the second link and see if that is what you need?

Comment: this is exactly what i need//... but it has a fall back ... that  when you type a word . and then modify it it will return the complete text ... lets say  :  you type     "This is a good reply "! now press back space nd replace "reply" by "Answer" and see its behaviour ../..

Comment: Hi, that is just because, as you can see in the javascript, I am comparing the previous values and replacing them with empty string to get the new one. If you want to track backspace etc, you need another function which compares them.

Comment: btw backspace has keycode 8 I think, so you can use that in if else block

Answer (score 0):

You could always do a regex replacing what was in the textbox before with nothing and that becomes the new value.